# Can we have a single application gateway for all VMSS created in different regions?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-web-app-firewall

Can we have a single Application Gateway for all VMSS created in different regions?
If yes please share the possible options.

Comment: application gateways are based on single region just like load balancers. you need to use traffic manager or azure front door (in preview) services for cross region traffic distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment mentioned, we could not have a single Application gateway for all VMSS created in a different region since Application Gateway is always deployed in a virtual network subnet and it directly supports to deploy the VMSS as the backends in the same region and virtual network as the Application gateway.

As a workaround, you could use a public IP address as the backend for communicating with instances outside of the virtual network as long as there is IP connectivity. Read more details about [backend pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-components#backend-pool). So you may use a public-facing load balancer associated with the VMSS.

Furthermore, you also could use [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) to distribute traffic across multiple Application Gateways in different datacenters. Or use [Azure Front Door Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/) provides a scalable and secure entry point for fast delivery of your global web applications.

Comment: Thanks. Suppoese I have added 3 Application gateway in traffic manager. Is there any way I can send request to specific application gateway dynamically. From my application I will select which application gateway I would like to serve the request,?

Comment: Check the [Traffic Manager routing methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods) to determine how to route network traffic to the various service endpoints.

Comment: i have gone through the routing methods but my problem is still not resolved. I need custom routing method where problematically i should be able to redirect the request to specific application gateway.

Comment: Well, the traffic manager works at the DNS level. Simply, If you have two healthy backends behind it, TM help client to select the endpoints based on the routing rules like  Priority, Performance, Geographic and so on. when one backend is not healthy, TM will help client redirect to another healthy endpoint. Is this what you expect?

Comment: Azure Front Door Service is now GA and a layer 7 global traffic management service. For your requirements as seen from this thread, AFD seems like the right choice.